# I have a completely PHP, codeigniter based website and want to add some blogs to the site in separate <div>

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I want to keep all my design the way it is, including my navigation. I just want //to integrate a wordpress blog part to it. I try to use

```
<iframe width="391" height="231" src="WWW" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I deleted the W’s and put our unique wordpress address but here its shows full wordpress site inside that div. I wanted to show only the blog part. while clicking the blog it will show the entire details.

Comment: i'm really new to this wordpress  so please help in step by step .Any help from anyone Thanx in advances..!

Comment: is your wordpress is on the same server?

Comment: @jogesh-pi---- No ..the wordpress  is on different server..

Comment: actually i want to integrate different wordpress blogs in different  <div> of page but the server of each blog will be different..

Comment: now i'm trying to integrate a blog in this site by using require function ..with in the same server by creating a blog my self.... but it shows error

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 52

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require(http://localhost/nayana/vaccines/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 52

Comment: Iframes are not a very elegant approach to solving the problem. Use a RSS reader in your CodeIgniter application and cache the results, e.g. on an hourly basis.

Answer (score 0):

Well iframe is ment to show a complete webpage. So you cant achieve it directly. There are some work arounds though.

1) **If you own the blog that you want in your iframe:** If you own the blog then just goto wp-content/themes/your-theme/header.php and wp-content/themes/your-theme/footer.php. Remove everything except the css and js files.(i mean remove all the div's,menu,sidebars etc that you dont want to be shown). Once everything is removed and you just have the barebone blogs, then use the normal iframe tag in your codeigniter site.

**2) If you dont own the blog:** If you dont own the blog then, you should search for in-page anchors within that website, use this tool to find these anchors. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/show-anchors-2/. Once you find the anchor just link to it with specific height and width.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/blog#anchorname_1" width="200px" height="100px"></iframe>
```

**3) The perfect way:** The perfect way would require you to know a bit about wordpress theme development. If you already have a blog theme, all you have to do is go into the theme's header and footer and replicate your website style. It doesn't have to be perfect replica, the are websites that use different themes just for blog. Just to make it look different then the website.

**4) Just create a simple blog in your own framework:** If you just want a simple blog, i would recommend just creating it within codeigniter. It would merely take an hour to build a basic blog in codeigniter. Depending on your requirement you might already have a users table to get the authors details, you just need to create a blog table with blogpost data. For comments you can just post generated code from [disqus](https://disqus.com/), its very powerful.

If you dont own the blog then its not necessary that the blog you are linking to have inpage anchors. you can search for an anchor tag with a name element in it . If you dont find it, then it will be very hard to link to a specific div. One way would be to grab all the content through **file_get_content** and then parse it and use regex to find that specific div and show it on your website. But if the blog changes its html then you will have t do it again. A better way would be to search for its **blog feed**. If it has a blog feed then you can do anything with it, you can even style the blog according to your theme.

Comment: i just want to use 2nd one but i dont know how to take in-page anchors within that website